# How do I get the offset for a time zone in ColdFusion

Tags: time, coldfusion, offset, zone

I have a need to get the offset (in hours) for any given time zone in Adobe ColdFusion. The idea is to pass in a time zone (America/Phoenix) and get back it's offset taking into account daylight savings.

Well after looking for what seemed forever, I realized CF doesn't have a way to do it. You need to delve into it's underbelly (JAVA) to get what you need. So, with a little help from a post by Ben Nadel on time zones, I figured it out and decided to pass on what I learned to a fellow dev traveler who may need it one day.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/alumniq/momentcfc

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>
    /*
    Author: Steve Holland (Avant Solutions Group)
    Website: www.avantsolutionsgroup.com
    License: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
    */
    private struct function calcTZOffset(required string timeZoneID, boolean returnTimezones="false") {
        // Init the timezome java class
        var tz = createObject( "java", "java.util.TimeZone" );

        // Get the timezone info
        var tzInfo = tz.getTimeZone(
            javaCast( "string", arguments.timeZoneID )
        );

        // Get the offset for the timezone
        var tzOffset = tzInfo.getOffset(
            javaCast("long", 0)
        );

        // Get the offset hours
        var tzOffsetHours = tzOffset / 3600000;

        //Check if the timezone is observing DST
        var inDST = tzInfo.observesDaylightTime();
        var tzOffsetHoursDST = inDST ? tzOffsetHours + 1 : tzOffsetHours;

        //Return
        var offset = {
            inDST = inDST,
            timeZone = arguments.timeZoneID,
            offsetMillis = tzOffset,
            offsetHours = tzOffsetHours,
            dstOffsetHours = tzOffsetHoursDST,
            timeZones = (arguments.returnTimezones)? tz.getAvailableIDs(): [] //Allow the user to return all the timezones (optional)
        };
        //writeOutput(tzOffset / 3600000);
        return offset;
    }

    tzID = "America/Denver";
    //tzID = "America/Phoenix";
    //tzID = "America/Los_Angeles";

    offset = calcTZOffset(tzID, false);

    //Dump out the results
    writeDump(var=offset);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the UTC offset in hours. I know it works in Lucee but should in ACF also.

```
var timeZone = getTimeZoneInfo("America/Phoenix");
WriteDump(timeZone.utcHourOffset);
```

Comment: That's too bad, its documented on the Adobe site but I don't see which versions support it on here. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/gettimezoneinfo.html

Comment: I see the issue, in ACF you can't pass in a timezone for some reason. That's too bad.

Comment: Right. CF doesn't let you pass parameters into that function. There isn't an out-of-the-box way to pull offsets from time zones. You have to dig into the JAVA underbelly to get it.